# Is creating an NSString or NSArray expensive?

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on optimizing the performance of my TableViews, and was wondering how expensive it is to create simple objects like a string or array within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The other option, of course, is to create the object as an ivar and set it each time a new cell gets loaded.

Which is better, creating a new object for each cell, or resetting the same object for each cell?

Note: I'm using these objects to do a number of different things, for example I'm creating a string to check the length of text I'm downloading from a server before passing it to the cell.

Comment: You'd only be storing a pointer to the object in question as an iVar though... what good would that do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creation of simple strings and arrays is not going to have an effect on the performance of your table. Creating *views* is expensive, and drawing them is also expensive - these are the areas you need to optimise for good scrolling.

Profile in instruments using the time profiler and core animation FPS instrument to be sure. This will highlight hotspots in your code, or alternatively give you a 60fps scroll rate*, in which case your work is done!

**on the device, of course*

Comment: Yeah, I have a bunch of image views, labels, and buttons in each cell, I'm going to be moving them over to drawRect to speed up performance that way. I just wanted to make sure creating simple objects like those weren't adding to the overhead. Time Profiler wasn't showing them taking up any time but doesn't hurt to ask. Thanks! :)